# How to sum data at Python with csv file

Tags: python

For example, I have csv file like below.

```
    apple orange tomato
0     4      5     2  
1     5      6     4
2     1      3     5
3     2      2     6
```

And, in conclusion, I want to make a new column as the sum of every fruits.

```
    apple orange tomato  total
0     4      5     2      11
1     5      6     4      15
2     1      3     5      9
3     2      2     6      10
```

It should be made only by 'for' command or is there more smart way like lambda?
Could you recommend some nice method? Thank you so much.

Comment: please share your code what you have done already

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

Return your data to a `list` then use `sum`.

```py
>>>a = [1,2,3]
>>>sum(a)
6
```

Or use `numpy.sum()`. Readmore [here](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-sum/)

```py
>>>import numpy as np
>>>np_array_2x3 = np.array([[0,2,4],[1,3,5]])
>>>np_array_2x3
array([[0, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 5]])
>>>np.sum(np_array_2x3, axis = 1)
array([6, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a large csv file, you could try and use pandas, which should make your code look cleaner:

```
# This will also read in your index column, you might
# have to deal with that in some other way

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis = 0).reset_index(drop = True)
df.to_csv("new_file.csv")

# Documentation for DataFrame.sum() is at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html
```